# Networking With Windows 7 And Windows Xp

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, networking, peer-to-peer

I Want Implement A Peer To Peer Network By Windows 7 And Windows Xp.How Quick And Professional Reference Can I Use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Networking-home-computers-running-different-versions-of-Windows

.